# How to connect Mongo db from Remote Machine

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, studio3t

I have installed and configured mongdb in one of the ubuntu machine. Now am trying to connect that mongodb database from my development machine (windows machine) through putty it works fine . But I want to connect through studio 3T but am unable to connect. Can anyone faced this issue can help me.
The steps I followed to connect mongodb from Studio 3T is following.

```
       1 Open Studio 3T
       2 Click Connect icon from toolbar and open connection manager popup window.
       3 Click New Connection from top right corner
       4 Gave some name "connection1" for connection
       5 Entered server name (ip address) and port number
       6 Selected Authentication tab, and entered authentication type as basic and username and password
       7 Click "Test connection" button
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow! did you try testing the port connectivity from the source machine to destination host (using telnet, netcat etc.)

what is the error seen when you do Test Connection?

Comment: Thank for the reply.. The following error message is occurred
Connection failed.

SERVER [<<IPAddress>>:27017] (Type: UNKNOWN) 
|_/ Connection error (MongoSocketOpenException): Exception opening socket
|____/ I/O error: connect timed out

Details:
Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address= <<IPAddress>>:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out}}]

Comment: have you tried testing the telnet connectivity from your dev machine to the host?
in the cmd prompt / bash shell try `telnet <ip_of_remote_machine> <servicePort>` 


does this go through?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. This issue is resolved by connecting the Studio 3T using SSH tunnel.

Comment: HI, can you guide how you did with ssh tunnel?